# Why @autowired is not required?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

why for a later method I do not need to require @Autowired to inject consumerFactory? And when I do so I receive a circular dependency exception.
Am I missing something fundamental, I guess yes.
Thanks for the help.

```java
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerConfig());
    }

    @Bean
    public KafkaListenerContainerFactory<
            ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String>> factory(
            ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory
    ) {

        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
                new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();

        factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory);
        return factory;
    }
```

Comment: `@Bean` methods are automatically autowired as documented.

Comment: If you annotate class with @Bean it's already under spring context and controlled by IoC container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring automatically detects that the `@Bean` annotated method `factory()` requires a `ConsumerFactory` to create an instance of `KafkaListenerContainerFactory`. Hence it already knows that it needs to provide a dependency for that.

`@Autowired` is only required if you have a class that requires a dependency, for example:

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

   @Autowired
   private ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory;

}
```

An alternative to this would be to define this as constructor argument, then you don't need `@Autowired` as well as it's already clear thanks to the constructor signature:

```
@Component
public class SomeClass {

   private ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory;

   public SomeClass(ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory) {
      this.consumerFactory = consumerFactory;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You use a method defined in the same class to initialize the ConsumerFactory object *(I suspect it's a configuration class annotated with **@Configuration**).*

The **@Bean** annotation creates another element and adds it to the set maintained by Spring engine.